# ERROR: Could not find the specified CDC channel in your Salesforce organization while trying to run Confluent Salesforce Connector

Tags: salesforce, cdc

When I am trying to run the Confluent Salesforce Connector, it's throwing the following error, saying the channel is not found in the organisation.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGf1Z.png)

I have configured the required entity in Change Data Capture for receiving any change events that happen on this entity.
[CDC configuration on UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZcl5.png)

I am able to subscribe to it's corresponding channel '/data/SFDC_Job__ChangeEvent' through Workbench.
[Event on Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQhvl.png)

Channel configured in the connector is same as the one subscribe through Workbench.
[Subscribed channel name from log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJztG.png)

Is there any other configuration that I am missing here?